# What is renderPartial() function in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, renderpartial

I am a yiibie, I want to know what is `renderPartial()`, how it works and where we use it? Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The [renderPartial documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) is clear enough to understand it.

> Renders a view.
>
> The named view refers to a PHP script (resolved via getViewFile) that
>   is included by this method. If $data is an associative array, it will
>   be extracted as PHP variables and made available to the script.
>
> This method differs from render() in that it does not apply a layout
>   to the rendered result. It is thus mostly used in rendering a partial
>   view, or an AJAX response.

So when you need to show a whole page with layouts, you use render(). If you want to show only view html, you use renderPartial().

```
class Controller extends CController {
  // Main page
  public function actionIndex(){
    $this->render('index');
  }

  // For example, additional content uploaded via AJAX after page is loaded
  public function actionInfo(){
    $this->renderPartial('info');
  }
}
```